# Swift 3: Dismiss popup ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, viewcontroller

I have a little problem on dismissing a VC.

My Project has 2 Viewcontroller. Viewcontroller A and Viewcontroller B.

Viewcontroller A has a button. If i press this button, the second ViewController B pops up.

The second ViewController (B) has a button. 
If i click this button this action will begin:

```
    @IBAction func dismiss(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    self.presentedViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

This action should actually dismiss the Viewcontroller and should show me the Viewcontroller A again.

But nothing happens if i press this button.

Did I forgot something?

Answer (score 10):

Should be:

```
@IBAction func dismiss(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

`presentedViewController` of `Viewcontroller B` is nil, that is why nothing happens. `presentedViewController` of `Viewcontroller A` is your `Viewcontroller B`